# How to combine and parallelize two async calls in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, concurrency

If I have two async methods, i.e:

```
subscribeToUserPhone(userId: Int, callback:(String)->Unit)
```

and

```
subscribeToUserStatus(userId:Int, callback:(Int)->Unit)
```

I'd like to provide a convenience method:

```
fun subscribe(userId:Int , callback:(UserInfo)->Unit)

//where UserInfo = data class UserInfo(val phone:String, val status:Int)
```

The naive solution could be:

```
fun getUserInfo(userId:Int , callback:(UserInfo)->Unit) {
    userManager.subscribeToUserPhone(userId){ phone ->
        userManager.subscribeToUserStatus(userId){ status ->
              callback(phone,status)
        }
    }
}
```

It have two main issues

- user status is subscribed multiple  times if phone changes.
- Data is recovered sequentially, first the phone and then the status when it could be retrieved in parallel

My question is: Is there some solution built in in Kotlin that allows to handle this kind of situations easily? or do I need to program all the code for solving those issues

Comment: You should be using coroutines, not callbacks, and that'll make all _sorts_ of async programming much easier.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way I can think of to solve this is using Flows. You can convert each of these into a Flow, `combine` them to run them in parallel, and then handle the results together. Each time either callback is fired, the lambda after `combine` will be fired with the latest values from each of the callbacks.

```
val phoneFlow = callbackFlow<String> {
    val callback: (String)->Unit = { trySendBlocking(it) }
    subscribeToUserPhone(userId, callback)
    awaitClose { unsubscribeToUserPhone(callback) }
}
val statusFlow = callbackFlow<Int> {
    val callback: (Int)->Unit = { trySendBlocking(it) }
    subscribeToUserStatus(userId, callback)
    awaitClose { unsubscribeToUserStatus(callback) }
}
phoneFlow.combine(statusFlow) { phone, status -> 
        // do something with them
    }
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.Main) // only if not launching on a scope using Main
    .launchIn(someScope)
```